# Linux iSCSI - Limit max concurrent sessions

Tags: linux, iscsi

I would like to understand if, and how to, limit the maximum number of 
simultaneous connections to a specific LUN under CentOS Linux, both with the old iSCSI stack (tgtadmin and friends) and the new one (targetcli and the likes).

I am exporting a LUN with a general purpose filesystem (non cluster 
aware) and I would be 100% sure that only a single machine at a time can 
mount it.

At the moment, I protected the iSCSI LUN with both an IP-based access 
list and a username/password combo, but hard limiting the maximum number of connections opened against it to 1 (one) would be a nice thing...

As I have mixed RHEL 6 and 7 environment, I am interested in how to do 
that on both the old and new iSCSI stack.

Thank you all.